# Use Pandas with Python3

Tags: python, pandas, import

I try to use pandas, but when I import pandas with the python interpreter I have the following error message:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import pandas.core.config_init
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/config_init.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas.core.format import detect_console_encoding
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.index import Index, MultiIndex, _ensure_index
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import PerformanceWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 5, in <module>
    import csv
  File "/home/sebastien/Documents/visualStudio/Python3_ex/Depute/analysis/csv.py", line 11, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns # Pimp my Matplotlib
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/seaborn/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import palettes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/seaborn/palettes.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/seaborn/utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    pandas_has_categoricals = LooseVersion(pd.__version__) >= "0.15"
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I have the same problem when I launch a script. 
I work with Linux Mint. 
Everyone has an idea of what happen ?

Thank you so much,

Sebastien

Comment: Have you installed pandas ?

Comment: Perhaps a better question is: How did you install Pandas? From those error messages it's obviously on your system, but it doesn't look like it was installed correctly.

Comment: did you use pip or pip3? Linux mint comes with both python2 and python3 installed and pip3 workes for the default python3.5. Are you using python 3.5 or did you install another version of python? Can you try using ```pip list``` to make sure it is installed?

Comment: Hi everybody, 
    Thinks for your help ! I have pyhton2.7 and python3.5 on my Linux - Mint system. 
    I install pandas with :
sudo apt-get python3-pandas
then: 
 sudo apt-get python3-seaborn

    I also tried to install pandas with pip3. But I have difficulty to install pip3... 

    I install pip3 with: 

    sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip

    Then I tied "pip3 --help", but I has the following message: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and searched for quite a while, here my summary:

Frist of all, have you tried to **turn it off and on**? Sounds stupid, but worked for me.

Other proposed solutions:

```
pip uninstall pandas
```

and after that

```
pip install pandas
```

Depending on you version, you also can try:

```
pip install pandas==0.22
```

There might also be a chance that you have a problem with your enviroments, in this case you can try this:

```
python -m pip list -v
```

to check for the location of the package, look out for duplicates, which might be the reason.